# Extracting a field value from a nested array of arrays with objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

Been trying to extract values from fields with no luck. Tried using the `map` function by nesting it, as well as concating the fields to try and achieve my result but with no luck.

I am looking to take an object with an almost identical structure to this:

```
[{ 
   name: 'sean', 
   age: 26, 
   address: 
      [{ 
         street: 'red'
       }, 
       { 
         street: 'blue'
       }]
}];
```

From this structure, I want to be able to extract the street value and insert it into a new array. So the result should be:

`const newArray = ['red', 'blue'];`

The address field can have multiple objects inside of it, so the solution is able to scale for 1-to-many.

Comment: Use `.flatMap()`

Comment: If `newArray = ['red', 'blue']` is the actual expected result, then one simple `.map()` is enough. If there are more "Persons" then you would need another `.map()` for every "person". So... - What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I've been trying to use ```.find```, ```.flat```, ```.flatMap```, ```.map``` and ```.concat``` but must be using them wrong. Haven't been able to get the intended result from ```.map``` or ```.flatMap``` as suggested but will try again

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve] (of your most promising attempt) that shows the actual problem/error.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const input = [
  {
    name: 'sean',
    age: 26,
    address: [
      {street: 'red'},
      {street: 'blue'}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'foo',
    age: 1,
    address: [
      {street: 'yellow'},
      {street: 'green'}
    ]
  }
];

const newArray = input.flatMap(({address}) => address.map(({street}) => street));
console.log(newArray);
```

[`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) takes a callback function returning an array of values, and then returns an array of all the values inside the arrays returned by the callback. In other words, `array.flatMap(callback)` is semantically equivalent to `array.map(callback).flat()`.

You mentioned trying to use `reduce` and `concat` in your comment. However, according to [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#alternative):

> ```js
> var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
>
> arr.flatMap(x => [x, x * 2]);
> // is equivalent to
> arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat([x, x * 2]), []);
> // [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6, 4, 8]
> ```
>
> Note, however, that this is inefficient and should be avoided for large arrays: in each iteration, it creates a new temporary array that must be garbage-collected, and it copies elements from the current accumulator array into a new array instead of just adding the new elements to the existing array.